# templates in symfony

Tags: templates, symfony1

Hy,
I'm look for a way to do this on symfony:

I've to use a "box" a bit every where on my site... this box is resizable ... so the html/css is not simple... and i don't want to copy/paste it every where and the content of this box is not constant at all... so its not possible to make a partial template with a object variable... and pass all the content on a variable it's a bit annoying.

someyhing like this would be great:

```
<?PHP begin("mytemplate") ?>
"html content"
<?PHP end ?>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you need this "box" try this:

```
include_partial('mymodule/mypartial', array('variable1' => 'value1', 'variable2' => 'value2'));
```

and in your "mymodule/templates/_mypartial.php" use it like:

```
<div class="box"><?php echo $variable1 ?></div>
```

Comment: Excuse me but did you read what i've asked?


_I've to use a "box" a bit every where on my site... this box is resizable ... so the html/css is not simple... and i don't want to copy/paste it every where and the content of this box is not constant at all... **so its not possible to make a partial template with a object variable**... **and pass all the content on a variable it's a bit annoying**._

Comment: how's about passing a CSS class to the partial? And you might want to tone down your rhetoric, free help & gift horse & all that.

Comment: partials are the best way to maintain the code clean, check http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer

Comment: You could see if a "component slot" suits your needs. Just Google for it or look it up in the Symfony docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use partials you can use **components** and define each variable into the component action. Check [Symfony's Components Slots](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_component_slots) (this is for v1.2 but works in v1.4).

Comment: yes but the variable will be the content of the slot...

What I really need it's to decorate a partial...